# GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG env variable not working?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I am following the guide to install gitlab using docker from [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#pre-configure-docker-container).

I have provided the following Environment Variable when setting up the docker install of gitlab:

```sh
GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com/'; gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 30022; puma['worker_processes'] = 0; sidekiq['max_concurrency'] = 10; prometheus_monitoring['enable'] = false; postgresql['shared_buffers'] = '256MB'; gitaly['cgroups_count'] = 2; gitaly['cgroups_mountpoint'] = '/sys/fs/cgroup'; gitaly['cgroups_hierarchy_root'] = 'gitaly'; gitaly['cgroups_memory_enabled'] = true; gitaly['cgroups_memory_limit'] = 250000; gitaly['cgroups_cpu_enabled'] = true; gitaly['cgroups_cpu_shares'] = 512; gitaly['concurrency'] = [ { 'rpc' => '/gitaly.SmartHTTPService/PostReceivePack', 'max_per_repo' => 3 }, { 'rpc' => '/gitaly.SSHService/SSHUploadPack', 'max_per_repo' => 3 } ]; gitaly['env'] = { 'LD_PRELOAD' => '/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/libjemalloc.so', 'MALLOC_CONF' => 'dirty_decay_ms:1000,muzzy_decay_ms:1000', 'GITALY_COMMAND_SPAWN_MAX_PARALLEL' => '2' }; gitlab_rails['time_zone'] = 'GMT'; gitlab_rails['display_initial_root_password'] = true;"
```

In case you're wonding where this comes from? See [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/memory_constrained_envs.html).

The docker install works fine and I can access the Gitlab GUI.

As you can see that I have setup an option of `gitlab_rails['display_initial_root_password']`. But when I try and get the initial password, it gives the following in the container `logs`:

```
password: *** - You opted not to display initial root password to STDOUT.
```

This makes me wonder if providing the environment var `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG` makes any difference or not? How do I check it?
I would like to make these settings permanent. What's the best way to do it? How do I make the above settings permanent?

PS I am deploying it on `rancher 2.6` using `k3s` if that makes a difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to permanently change settings was to edit the `gitlab.rb` file. This file gets created for the first time when you spin up the container.

Answer (score 0):

If you do modify the gitlab.rb, note that [GitLab 15.3 (Aug. 2022)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/08/22/gitlab-15-3-released/#omnibus-improvements) is deprecating some of the gitaly cgroup setting:

> Gitaly is now using [new cgroup configurations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/gitaly/configure_gitaly.html#control-groups).
>
> The following configs are to be deprecated:
>
> ```
> gitaly['cgroups_count'], 
> gitaly['cgroups_memory_limit'], 
> gitaly['cgroups_memory_enabled], and 
> gitaly['cgroups_cpu_enabled'].
> ```
>
> If you use any of the previous settings, ensure you remove them or switch to the new ones, before the 16.0 major release.